# Get.height and Get.width are printing 0.0 on first time in release mode?

Tags: flutter, height, width, flutter-getx, state-management

I am using **Getx state management** for my project. `Get.width` and `Get.height` is printing **0.0** when the widget build for the first time after refreshing the screen with `setState((){})` it prints the actual value. I have declared and initialized the height and width commonly.

**This is my code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      enableLog: true,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(Get.height);
    print(Get.width);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Debug Output:**

[image: DeBug Image]

**Release Output:**

[image]

First, it prints the value `0.0` after pressing the floating button it started to print the actual value.

How can I solve this issue? In my previous projects, it was working fine.

get: ^4.6.5

**My flutter Doctor:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [issues #2523](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/2523) on github there is no way to fix for now, but you can try to use:

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
```

more info about [Get and MediaQuery](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/486#issuecomment-677892438)

but this error maybe happens when the UI has not been sized and laid out on the screen yet

Comment: In my previous project, it was working fine. But, I can't reproduce it. Hope they fix this soon.

Comment: follow github, the updates will be mentioned

Answer (score 1):

In the splash screen I have used the `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` and
`MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` for height and width. Then in the other pages I have used the `Get.width` and `Get.height`.Now everything works fine. If there is no height and width property in the `Splash screen()` then use the `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` and
`MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` in the login page and the home page. Hope this solve the issue.